# How to reload UITableView section with different row count?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

This is a simple idea, but I can't seem to figure out the right solution.

I have a UITableView with many sections, including a header view.

I would like to be able to hide/remove each of the tableview cells in the sections I have, and then reload them back in with a nice animation.

My problem is that the number of sections could be different than before, and the number of rows in the sections could be different than before...

I can't simply fade out the entire tableview, and then reload it, and fade it back in because I need the header view to always be visible and scroll with the tableview.

I need to have them removed because the hiding and showing will be a nice "fade" animation with an activity indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the tableView methods

```
[self.tableView insertSections:(nonnull NSIndexSet *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)]
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(nonnull NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)]
```

They will allow you to animate the insertion of new rows / sections. For Deletion there are similar methods, except they are called "deleteSections..." and "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths...".

Just take care that after insertion / deletion, these tableView's delegate functions return the current values:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { }
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
```

And "correct" means: Amount of sections / rows before the insertion / deletion, plus or minus the amount of rows and sections after the insertion / deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Here index path is the specific rows that you want to reload. If you are changing the number of rows, you have to change the number of items in the data source. Or you can change the value returned by numberOfRowsInSection

Answer (score 0):

For chaining animations you could use

```
let pathsForNewCells = [indexPathOne, indexPathTwo, indexPathThree]

myTableView.beginUpdates()
myTableView.insertRows(at: pathsForNewCells, with: [UITableViewRowAnimation])
myTableView.endUpdates()
```

thus, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates) the height will animate without reloading the cells.